# Show Vue components within VuePress

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I want to display customized Vue.js components such as a `<b-button>` for example, on a VuePress markdown page.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to call any Vue component into the md page content or visa versa (by use of slots).

Assuming your component is in the components folder you can reference it directly with . If you have the component in a sub folder ie components/ui/ then you would need to add the path seperated by a hyphen .

You can also use frontmatter to pass data to the component.

[vuepress docs - using components](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#using-components)